# Tkinter button inserting into sqlite table fails

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I'm making a small tkinter app wchich uses sqlite as a database.
I'm constantly getting a error when trying to insert a row into the table. It happens when the button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

pol=sqlite3.connect('/home/tom/Documents/VScode/bazalogowanie/baza.db') 
kurs=pol.cursor() 
kurs.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bazal (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, login TEXT, haslo, TEXT)')

##def zapis(login, haslo):
    ##pass



def odczyt():
        cala_baza = kurs.execute('SELECT * FROM bazal')
        for uzytkownik in cala_baza:
            print(uzytkownik)

def koniec():
    pol.commit()
    pol.close()
    exit()

root=Tk()  
root.geometry("400x400")
topFrame = Frame(root).pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root).pack(side = "bottom")

Label(root, text="LOGIN").pack()
LOGIN=Entry(root)
LOGIN.pack()
root.title("BAZA LOGOWANIA")
Label(root, text="HASŁO").pack()
HASLO=Entry(root)
HASLO.pack()
login = LOGIN.get()
haslo = HASLO.get()
Button(root, text = "Login", command=lambda:kurs.execute(f'INSERT INTO bazal (login, haslo) VALUES ("{login}","{haslo})"')).pack()
Button(root, text="def log", command=lambda:odczyt()).pack()
Button(root, text= "zamknij", command=lambda:koniec()).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/tom/Documents/VScode/bazalogowanie/baza logowanie.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    Button(root, text = "Login", command=lambda:     kurs.execute(f'INSERT INTO bazal (login, haslo) VALUES ("{login}","{haslo})"')).pack()
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/tom/Documents/VScode/bazalogowanie/baza logowanie.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    Button(root, text = "Login", command=lambda:     kurs.execute(f'INSERT INTO bazal (login, haslo) VALUES ("{login}","{haslo})"')).pack()
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

I do not know where this error comes from
can I ask for help?

Comment: Note that once you get the INSERT statement working, you will be inserting blank values.  You did the `login = LOGIN.get()` and `haslo = HASLO.get()` *immediately* after creating the Entries; the user cannot possibly have typed in anything yet!  You need to do the `.get()`s inside the Button's `command=` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got The solution there is a simple mistake in your code.
Generally, This error show when you miss closing any parentheses in the code

**Change**

`Button(root, text = "Login", command=lambda:kurs.execute(f'INSERT INTO bazal (login, haslo) VALUES ("{login}","{haslo}")')).pack()`
**To**

`Button(root, text = "Login", command=lambda:kurs.execute(f'INSERT INTO bazal (login, haslo) VALUES ("{login}","{haslo})"')`

The Error is because you put double quote after parentheses there (`"{login}","{haslo})"`).

You can see the same error solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116641/how-to-fix-sqlite3-operationalerror-incomplete-input-when-the-error-is-rega#:%7E:text=20,Edit).

Comment: You have reversed the two code blocks.

Comment: @acw1668 What do you mean.

Comment: It means that change A to B is actually change B to A.